# ¿ Cómo convertir un objeto a un string con delimitador?

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de objeto de una clase, la estoy recorriendo pero necesito convertir el objeto a un string con algún delimitador (por ejemplo por coma)

```
List<RipsAC> listaRipsAc = new List<RipsAC>();
```

Estoy recorriendo esta lista con un foreach

```
foreach (var error in numFactur)
            {
                    erroresAc.Add("El campo Numero Factura no es valido: ("+error.NumFactura +") <---> linea: "+ /* string concatenado del objeto */ + " <---> Ruta Archivo: "+error.RutaArchivo);
            }
```

Necesito mostrar el objeto delimitando las propiedades.

Comment: Si no es un objeto con muchas propiedades, te recomiendo la respuesta de Randall Sandoval. En caso contrario, la respuesta de Tuco puede ser mas apropiada, aunque es menos eficiente al utilizar Reflection.

Comment: @Pikoh de hecho la respuesta de @Tuco me parece apropiada ya que si en el objeto `listaRipsAc ` tienes 100 o 200 propiedades concatenar una por una sería un trabajo muy tedioso y usando `Reflection` se facilita completamente el trabajo

Comment: @Pikoh el punto es que aunque sean una o 1000 propiedades se debe implementar la forma más automática posible, algunas veces la programación se vuelve impredecible y un objeto puede ir creciendo en el número de propiedades, lo cual se tiene que ir haciendo modificaciones cada que un objeto cambia

Comment: @Flxtr correcto. Lo que intento exponer es que el uso de Reflection siempre tiene un coste en cuanto a memoria y velocidad de ejecución que hay que evaluar y que si el objeto no tiene muchas propiedades y no está previsto que estas se modifiquen,la respuesta de Randall es preferible en mi opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante Reflection puedes obtener las propiedades del objeto y concatenarlas con ","

Importar System.Reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Tu metodo:

```
foreach (var error in numFactur)
        {
          erroresAc.Add("[ERROR EN FACTURA BLA BLA] " + GetPropiedades(error) +" [MAS DE TU FORMATO...]" );
        }
```

...

```
private string GetPropiedades(Object o)
    {
        Type t = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pis = t.GetProperties();
        string[] valores = pis.Select(p => p.Name + " : " + p.GetValue(o)).ToArray();
        string delimitados = string.Join(",", valores );
        return delimitados;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes sobre-escribir el método `ToString();`, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173154.aspx) te queda información sobre esto.

```
//Como sobre-escribir
class Objeto{
   public override string ToString(){
       return "soy un objeto con un delimitador coma, ";
   }  
}

//ejecución
List<Objeto> listaObjetos = new List<Objeto>
Objeto obj1 = new Objeto();
Objeto obj2 = new Objeto();
Objeto obj3 = new Objeto();

listaObjetos.add(obj1);
listaObjetos.add(obj2);
listaObjetos.add(obj3);
foreach(var obj in listaObjetos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()+"\n");
}
```

**Resultado**

> soy un objeto con un delimitador coma,
>
> soy un objeto con un delimitador coma,
>
> soy un objeto con un delimitador coma,